# Handling categorical features with varying number of categories

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, feature-engineering

I have a dataset for a classification problem.  Some of the features are categorical and I wish to encode them in some way for a basic logistic regression.  However, my data is partially in a long format.  For example

df

```
idx  f1   f2   ...
0    123  123
1    456  456
2    789   789
...
```

df2

```
idx  f_cat
0    string1
0    string2
0    string3
1    string1
2    string1
2    string2
2    string4
```

The secondary dataframe that I want to include has multiple categories within the feature.  Furthermore, it varies with respect to how many of the categories are assigned to each index (as many as 16 but majority are in 1-6).  I am trying to avoid use one hot encoding as there is very high cardinality (ie. 100s).  There is also no order to the categories, the order is completely random and therefore I cannot just truncate to the first 'n' categories.  Any suggestions on how I could encode this categorical feature?

FYI, I am primarily using python but happy to accept other language based answers.

Answer (score 1):

I Came across this issue, I used one hot encoding on the top X most frequent categories.

Edit: I found the code of how I did it.

```
for col in df.columns :
    df[col]=df[col].values.astype(str)
    if col in cat_features:
        unique_vals = df[col].unique()
        if len(unique_vals) <= 10:
            df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=col)
            df = pd.concat([df, df_encoded], axis=1)
        else:
            top_10_vals = df[col].value_counts().index[:10]
            for val in top_10_vals:
                col_name = col + '_' + val
                df[col_name] = np.where(df[col] == val, 1, 0)
       df=df.drop(col,axis=1)
```